# JQuery UI Slider Positioning

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, slider

I am using the slider from http://jqueryui.com/slider/ , especially the fixed slider. I want to move this slider down to the bottom of the page, but when I tried to set margin-bottom: 5px  in the .ui-slider and ui-slider-range-min, nothing happens. Can somebody please assist me?

```
.ui-slider {
position: relative;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
width: 1.2em;
height: 1.2em;
cursor: default;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
font-size: .7em;
display: block;
border: 0;
background-position: 0 0;
}

/* For IE8 - See #6727 */
.ui-slider.ui-state-disabled .ui-slider-handle,
.ui-slider.ui-state-disabled .ui-slider-range {
filter: inherit;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
height: .8em;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
top: -.3em;
margin-left: -.6em;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range {
top: 0;
height: 100%;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min {
left: 0;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max {
right: 0;
}

.ui-slider-vertical {
width: .8em;
height: 100px;
}
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-handle {
left: -.3em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: -.6em;
}
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-range {
left: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-range-min {
bottom: 0;
}
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-range-max {
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: let me know if my answer below does not address your question, also you should go back on accept answers on some of your previous questions.  (You can click the white check mark to the left of an answer to accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the css on the original slider and not on the classes added by `jquery-ui-slider`

Here is an example:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

`CSS`

```
#slider {
    width:80%;
    margin-left:25px;
     margin-top:400px;   
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/vvg7j/)

Comment: I noticed that adding `margin-top: 5px;` to the slider's div moves the slider's range down 5 pixels in relation to the slider. This is fixed by adding `margin: 0px;` to the `.ui-slider-range`.